# How to manually update input value while using Chakra UIs useNumberInput hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks, chakra-ui

I'm currently using Chakra UIs `useNumberInput` hook for a custom number input component. I need to be able to update the input value returned by `useNumberInput` manually in the event that my API call fails, so that it can be set to the last value stored to Redux. Is there any way to do this while still taking advantage of `useNumberInput`?

```
function HookUsage() {
  const { getInputProps, getIncrementButtonProps, getDecrementButtonProps } =
    useNumberInput({
      step: 0.01,
      defaultValue: 1.53,
      min: 1,
      max: 6,
      precision: 2,
    })

  const inc = getIncrementButtonProps()
  const dec = getDecrementButtonProps()
  const {
    // This is the value I want to be able to update or reset manually
    value,

    ...inputProps
  } = getInputProps()

  return (
    <HStack maxW='320px'>
      <Button {...inc}>+</Button>
      <Input value={value} {...inputProps} />
      <Button {...dec}>-</Button>
    </HStack>
  )
}
```

Pulled the above from Chakra UIs documentation:

- https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/number-input/usage#create-a-mobile-spinner

Am I better off just ditching `useNumberInput` and building my own solution in this case?

Answer (score 1):

```
function HookUsage(props: UseNumberInputProps) {
  const { getInputProps, getIncrementButtonProps, getDecrementButtonProps } = useNumberInput(props)

  const inc = getIncrementButtonProps()
  const dec = getDecrementButtonProps()
  const {
    // This is the value I want to be able to update or reset manually
    value,

    ...inputProps
  } = getInputProps()

  return (
    <HStack maxW='320px'>
      <Button {...inc}>+</Button>
      <Input {...inputProps} />
      <Button {...dec}>-</Button>
    </HStack>
  )
}

const Usage = () => {
  const props = {
    step: 0.01,
    min: 1,
    max: 6,
    precision: 2,
  }
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1.53)
  return <VStack>
    <HookUsage value={value} {...props} />
    <Button onClick={() => setValue(2.23)}>update to 2.23</Button>
  </VStack>
}
```